# example of a mathematical proof formalized by type theory rather than set theory.

Tags: proof-theory, type-theory

I've been reading on type theory, and it being a possible foundation of mathematics. I have to say it is all very abstract to me. I'm very used to using set theory to think about mathematical proofs, but I find it very hard to imagine using type theory to think about mathematical proofs (I hardly understand type theory yet btw).

So in order **to make it less abstract and more concrete:** Can you give an example of a mathematical proof, and how it would be formalized in type theory, rather than in set theory?

For example, let's take the proposition:

> Proposition. Let $x$ be a real number and $x_n$ a sequence of real numbers. Let $f$ be a function continuous at $x$). Then if $x_n$ converges to $x$, then $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$.

The way I think about proving this formally, would be to state first the definition of $x_n$ converging to $x$:
$$\forall \epsilon_{\in\mathbb R},\exists N_{\in \mathbb N},\forall n_{\in \mathbb N}:\left[(e>0 \land n>N)\implies|x_n-x|<\epsilon\right]$$

Then we can do the same for continuity of $f$. And then we simply apply some basic deductive axioms to get to the conclusion. I won't write down all the steps because you can imagine what it looks like.

**I however, cannot imagine what the equivalent process would look like for type theory.** **Can you show how you would prove this theorem (or any other simpler theorem) formally using type theory rather than set theory and first order logic?**

Comment: You might be interested in the later chapters of the HoTT book, and in particular chapters 10 (Set theory) and 11  (Real numbers) which is available at https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/

Comment: I hope you may be interested in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567265/why-is-it-worth-spending-time-on-type-theory). Also, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612122/axiom-of-choice-type-theory-proof?rq=1

Comment: You might note that prop 11.3.39 of the HoTT book uses your proposition as a definition of continuous, so your particular example won't be proven therein!

Comment: Everything in the Coq libraries, the Agda libraries, the NuPRL libraries is an example of a (truly) formal proof in an intuitionistic type theory. Then everything in the Isabelle/HOL, HOL4, HOL Light libraries are examples in a non-dependent type theory. I'd be a bit surprised if you've actually seen a truly formal, i.e. machine-checked, set theoretic proof. MetaMath, TLAPS, and Mizar (though that's a bit ambiguous) would provide examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you give an example of a mathematical proof, and how it would be formalized in type theory, rather than in set theory?

[Here](https://github.com/maximedenes/native-coq/blob/3623a4d9fe95c165f02f7119c0e6564a83a9f4c9/theories/Reals/Rfunctions.v) is an example of a simple proof in [Coq](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs430/sectionNotes/section1/CoqTutorial.pdf), which is based on dependent type theory.

```
Lemma pow_add : forall (x:R) (n m:nat), x ^ (n + m) = x ^ n * x ^ m.
Proof.
  intros x n; elim n; simpl; auto with real.
  intros n0 H' m; rewrite H'; auto with real.
Qed.
```

And here is a longer proof of a different lemma:

```
Lemma poly : forall (n:nat) (x:R), 0 < x -> 1 + INR n * x <= (1 + x) ^ n.
Proof.
  intros; elim n.
  simpl; cut (1 + 0 * x = 1).
  intro; rewrite H0; unfold Rle; right; reflexivity.
  ring.
  intros; unfold pow; fold pow;
    apply
      (Rle_trans (1 + INR (S n0) * x) ((1 + x) * (1 + INR n0 * x))
        ((1 + x) * (1 + x) ^ n0)).
  cut ((1 + x) * (1 + INR n0 * x) = 1 + INR (S n0) * x + INR n0 * (x * x)).
  intro; rewrite H1; pattern (1 + INR (S n0) * x) at 1;
    rewrite <- (let (H1, H2) := Rplus_ne (1 + INR (S n0) * x) in H1);
      apply Rplus_le_compat_l; elim n0; intros.
  simpl; rewrite Rmult_0_l; unfold Rle; right; auto.
  unfold Rle; left; generalize Rmult_gt_0_compat; unfold Rgt;
    intro; fold (Rsqr x);
      apply (H3 (INR (S n1)) (Rsqr x) (lt_INR_0 (S n1) (lt_O_Sn n1)));
        fold (x > 0) in H;
          apply (Rlt_0_sqr x (Rlt_dichotomy_converse x 0 (or_intror (x < 0) H))).
  rewrite (S_INR n0); ring.
  unfold Rle in H0; elim H0; intro.
  unfold Rle; left; apply Rmult_lt_compat_l.
  rewrite Rplus_comm; apply (Rle_lt_0_plus_1 x (Rlt_le 0 x H)).
  assumption.
  rewrite H1; unfold Rle; right; trivial.
Qed.
```

Coq allows you to define [tactics](https://www.cse.iitm.ac.in/~krishna/courses/2015/odd-cs6848/sf/MoreCoq.html) (like the `rewrite` and `intros` tactics above), which help you do the proof. They have a bunch of [built in ones](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/coq-tacindex.html) as well.